# Pressing force of a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance, magnetostatics

If a current is passed through bundle of loosely coiled, insulated wire the space between the wires rapidly contracts, crushing it down into a disk.  How can this crushing force be calculated?

I know that in a vacuum the magnetic field created by a solenoid is B =  μIN/l (μ = permeability of free space, N = turns, I = current, l = length), so reducing the length increases the magnetic field strength.  I'm not sure how to describe the force in favour of a smaller L though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) First we give an approximate force-based treatment for a solenoid whose length, $l$, is several times greater than its radius, $r$.

Consider the North end of the solenoid. There's a very simple argument to show that half the flux in the main part of the solenoid (that is half of $\pi r^2\ \mu_0 N I/l$) escapes through the sides of the solenoid before reaching the geometrical end of the solenoid. Therefore if $B_{rad}$ is the radial component of flux density at the surface of the solenoid at distance $z$ from its end,
$$\int_0^{z_0} B_{rad}\ 2\pi r dz =\tfrac 12 \frac{\pi r^2\ \mu_0 N I}l.$$
in which $z_0$ is the notional distance from the geometrical end at which there is no more radial escape of flux.

However in length $dz$ of solenoid there are $dz\ (N/l)$ turns, so a length $2\pi r\ dz\ (N/l)$ of wire. Therefore the total (axial) force on the North end part of the solenoid due to the radial field will be
$$\int_0^{z_0} B_{rad}\ \ I\ 2\pi r \tfrac {N}l dz\ \ =\ \tfrac {NI}l \int_0^{z_0} B_{rad}\ 2\pi r dz\ =\ \frac{\pi r^2\ \mu_0 N^2 I^2}{2l^2}.$$

This force acts towards the middle (lengthways) of the solenoid; a similar force acts on the South Pole end of the solenoid, so there is a compressive stress on the solenoid.

[It might be argued that, rather than $2\pi r$, the length of a turn is $\sqrt{(2\pi r)^2+(l/N)^2}$. So indeed it is, but the axial component, $(l/N)\hat z$, of the turn gives rise in the presence of $B_{rad}$ to tangential forces (that cancel over a complete turn anyway) rather than to an axial magnetic force!]

(b) The result just obtained agrees with what we get using $|F_{\text{axial}}|= -\frac {\partial U}{\partial l}$ in which $U$ is the magnetic energy stored in the solenoid. So, (ironically) ignoring end-effects and treating $B$ as uniform throughout the interior volume of the solenoid,
$$U=\frac 1{2\mu_0} B^2 \pi r^2 l=\frac 1{2\mu_0} \left( \frac {\mu_0 NI}l\right)^2 \pi r^2 l=\frac{\mu_0 N^2 I^2}{2l}\pi r^2.$$

$$\text{so}\ \ \ \ |F_{\text{axial}}|= -\frac {\partial U}{\partial l}=\frac{\mu_0 N^2 I^2}{2l^2}\pi r^2.$$
The irony is that in this method, (b), we have ignored what was the very basis of the *force* method, (a) – end effects! The reason it is permissible in this method is our assumption that $l>>r$. The end effects (escape of flux through the sides of the solenoid) are pretty much confined to end lengths $z_0$ of solenoid of the same order as the solenoid radius, $r$.

Comment: I've added an energy treatment.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!